# All pairs of matrices whose product is a given low-rank matrix

Tags: matrices

Suppose we have an $n\times m$ matrix $M$ of rank $k\ll n$. Such a matrix can be decomposed
$$ M = A B $$
where $A$ is an $n\times k$ matrix and $B$ is a $k\times m$ matrix. Such a decomposition can be obtained for example using (compact) singular value decomposition
$$ M = U\Sigma V^* \\ A=U , B=\Sigma V^*$$

Clearly, this decomposition is not unique. For example, for any number $x$
$$ A=U \Sigma^{1-x}, B=\Sigma^x V^*$$
will also have $A B=M$

Is there a way of characterising or parametrizing the space of all matrices $A$ and $B$ (of known size $n\times k$ and $k\times m$ respectively) whose product is a given matrix $M$?

Comment: For any $k\times k$ invertible matrix C we still have $ (U C) (C^{-1}\Sigma V^*) = M$. This might be the whole set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Assume that $M=AB$ where $A:K^k\rightarrow K^n$ is one to one and $im(A)=im(M)$; note that $U:K^k\rightarrow K^n$ has same two properties. There is a unique $C:K^k\rightarrow K^k$ s.t. $A=UC$ and $C$ is a bijection. Indeed, $C$ is defined by $C(x)=U^{-1}(A(x))$.